# jQuery zoom zooms in too far

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery zoom for a product zoom.
This is the JS

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.image-zoom')
      .css('display', 'block')
      .parent()
      .zoom({
        url: $(this).find('img').attr('data-zoom')
      });
    });
</script>
```

However this zooms in too close. Is there a way to set how much the image should be zoomed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add property `magnify`

This value is multiplied against the full size of the zoomed image. The default value is 1, meaning the zoomed image should be at 100% of its natural width and height.